# MySQL Modeling: Relationship normalization & ring issue

Tags: mysql, relational-database, primary-key, relationship

I'm building this MySQL model to organize a movie collection.
It will manage both movies and series/episodes. Each movie/episode may have one or more audio stream and codecs for audio/video may vary. (don't mind subtitles for now)

I'm not an expert, so I'm seeking advice:

- **Ring relationships**.
  Someone told me long ago that when a model has a 'ring' relationship, meaning that the relationships in the model form a ring/loop (pictured), then the modelling is probably wrong. Is this wrong?
  [image]
- **multiple references**: table `movies_audios`
  In this table, `fk_movie_id` may refer to either `movies.movie_id` OR `episodes.episode_id`. Is this ok? I mean one primary key may refer to different tables?

[image]

**UPDATED** MODELING AFTER ABrowne's answer:

### [image]

"for a tv serie that is drama, you won't have an episode that is comedy"
[image]

**UPDATED** MODELING AFTER ABrowne's answer:
[image]

Comment: Four options on your outstanding problem: 1) a series_genre table linking genres to series. 2) a series fk on movies_genres 3) a rethink to the model 4) application logic to set all the movies to have the same genre when a series is saved. Not everything can be enforced in your object relationship model, this is one of those I think you should put in the application layer. You need to consider how you might be querying the series data.

Comment: To continue, if you searched by genre, you could pull all the movies and then group them by their series. You application logic on inserts just needs to ensure the integrity of your movie tables genre within a series.

Comment: I think like this: series, different from movies, will have only one genre. So I'd link `series.fk_genre_id` to `genres.genre_id`

Comment: The best thing to do is to test your thinking by applying it to your application. An ERD will evolve over time as you build your application and realise that the way you modelled it needs to be tweaked to suit the performance or searching requirements. Either way is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, 'ring relationships' as you refer to them are neither incorrect or correct, but do hint at a complex relationship.

In the relationships you describe, and movie 'could have' one or more codecs and a codec 'could have' one or more episodes. Assuming that our movie is 'Ironman', it could be encoded in H.264/MPEG-4 and MPEG-4 ASP. So this relationship appears correct and valid. A episode could also be encoded as H.264/MPEG-4, and a single encoding (a distribution/media such as a dvd, perhaps?) could have include multiple episodes. Maybe I have mis-understood your 'codec', so please correct be if I am wrong. This would create a many to many relationship between codec and episode with a missing table inbetween called 'distribution/media'.

Also the movie_audios, I assume you are refering to the different language audios that that episode/movie is about?

I would consider normalising your structure and consider something like this (this is just a skeleton):

```
video
- video_id
- plot
- fk_series_id
- series_no   <- this is the number within a series
- rating
- imdb_ref
- fk_genre_id    
- fk_codec_id  <- 1 to many relationship between codec and video

video_genre
- fk_video_id
- fk_genre_id

genre
- genre_id
- name

subtitles    
- fk_video_id 
- fk_language

audio
- audio_id
- fk_video_id
- fk_language_id

language
- language_id    

audio_codec
- fk_audio_id
- fk_codec_id

codec
- codec_id
- name

series
- series_id
- series_name
- fk_series_type_id

series_type
- series_type_id
- name
```

On the second part of your question on multiple ids on your current codec relationship, the difficulty is in how you look it up.

For example, assume that you have movie_id = 9, and your episode_id = 9, which is it, a movie or an episode? You can solve this a few ways:

1) put two foreign keys on the codec and use xor to determine depending on relationship existence

2) you can add a 'type' on the codec table. This will require your insert method to ensure it is correctly applied

3)you can ensure your ids are unique across both tables. A complex way of doing this is to do a lookup against both when you generate an id. You can even create this a trigger event on insert however the simpler way is to prefix the id with a letter, so that m9 is a movie and e9 is an episode.

---- updated post the update to the model ----

So reading the relationships and tables, they appear to be how I would imagine. A movie/episode (lets call it a recording) can have many genres, such as romantic & comedy. However there is one genre of a comedy. From this one genre we can correctly find all the recordings it relates to.

A recording can have many audios, and many subtitles. Each audio & each subtitle is in a language. Audios also have one audio codec. From a language or a codec we could find all the recordings it relates to.

A recording also has one video codec and a tv_series has many recordings.

I would reconsider your naming of 'movies' for something that is able to cover more generically what is included such as video or recording.

Also I would consider whether you have a need to list movies within a series, such as Ironman 1-3. This would question the naming of tv_series again to be something more generic.

To simplify your model you could merge codecs video & audio into one. If you need to tell the difference you could relate either put a type field on it, or a relationship to a codec_type table.

Comment: It is about that. A movie/episode will **always** have one and only one video stream(codec) but may have more than one audio stream/codec. I thought of merging table `tvshows` into `movies` and adding a column `is_tv_series` (bool). But I don't know if it would help.

Comment: I have updated my model to reflect your 1-n relationship on video codecs. episodes & movies are merged into one table videos, and video & audio codecs are merged into one table codecs. I am still assuming that a video may have multiple audio codecs, but shout if this is wrong. As for you flag, you can look for a series_type of TV Show, and find all the series, and the videos linked to those series. No need for a boolean flag on the video table.

Comment: 'a video may have multiple audio codecs' that is correct. A video may contain: A1: English 6ch DTS / A2: English 2ch AAC / A3: Other_lang MP3.

Comment: Have a go at implement the structure above and shout if you have an issues.

Comment: Please, check the modeling updated in the question body. Is that correct?

Comment: Now, for TV Series, the genre is not of the episode, but of the series. Should I link `tvs_series` to `movie_genres`? I mean.. for a tv serie that is drama, you won't have an episode that is comedy...

Comment: You are correct. I would be tempted to use a series_genres table to maintain that relationship and avoid confusion. Also see my comments at the end of the post above.

Comment: Done. There is only one issue now. see the note in the last model